# Usar DatePicker em uma Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, datepicker

Olá!, 
estou a tentar fazer com que um datepicker faça parte do layout da activity como mostra figura a baixo:

[image: Registo no Facebook]

Já andei a procura pela internet, mas todos os exemplos que encontro falam de  DatePickerDialog, e não seria isso que pretendia.
Alguma Solução? 
Obrigado!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow in Portuguese. In case you haven't noticed, this is the SO Portuguese community, if you're looking to get help in english please visit the [SO English Community](http://stackoverflow.com/questions). If you're looking to get help in portuguese, please edit and translate your question.

Comment: Obrigado, eu achei que fosse o próprio site a traduzir-se, irei traduzir e colocar tambem no SO English Community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe o [DatePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) que pode ser usado como uma *view* normal em qualquer *layout*.

Para que seja apresentado como está na imagem da pergunta deve utilizar os atributos `datePickerMode` e `calendarViewShown` com os seguintes valores:

```
android:datePickerMode="spinner"
android:calendarViewShown="false"
```

Comment: Exatamente, é isso mesmo que queria!, obrigado! Precisava de era de alterar a cor da fonte , há forma?

Comment: Ainda bem que pude ajudar e bem vindo ao StackOverflow. Veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) a forma de proceder quando uma resposta te foi útil. Em ralação à cor da fonte veja [isto](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31321039/2556111).

Comment: Ja tinha visto esse post, mas resultados sem sucesso

Comment: O problema é que existem várias versões do DatePicker, ele tem mudado com novas versões do Android.

Comment: Vou abrir um novo post, ver se consigo obter uma resposta, obrigado mais uma vez!